# Launch image - iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have two files for the Launch image for my iPhone app.

1. Launch.jpg: 320x480
2. Launch@2x.jpg: 640x960

In my .plist, I have the following key-pairs (amongst others):

1. Launch image (iPhone) = Launch.jpg
2. Status bar is initially hidden = NO

However, when my app first launches, the top 20 pixels or so of the Launch image are blocked because of the status bar. How can I tell my Launch image to start below the status bar upon launch?

Comment: Why not just make the top 20 pixels of your Launch.jpg blank?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. What software can I use for that?

Comment: Is the status bar exactly 20 pixels?

Comment: Yes, it's always 20 pixels (or 40 at @2x), and you can use any image editor - Photoshop, etc. - to blank out the top 20 pixels.

Comment: remove them rather than making them blank, so that you'll have 320x460 & 640x920

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the status bar to be present on the launch screen, your best option is to modify the launch images themselves to make room for the status bar. As the top 20 pixels is being cut off by the bar, simply modifying your `Launch.jpg` to have the top 20 pixels blanked-out will do the trick.

If you don't need the status bar on the launch screen but want it on the application, set it to hidden in your `Info.plist` and have your application do:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

once it finishes launching.

Comment: I don't need the status bar to be on the Launch screen. How can I have the status bar be added after the launch screen is shown?

Comment: Edited to hopefully answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the *Status bar is initially hidden* to *YES* to hide the status bar while the splash image is shown.

Comment: If he's specifically setting it to NO in the settings, I suspect he wants it that way.